# Replace the node name with the attribute value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this xml :

```
<Item name="Alpha">
    <Field name="CreationDateTime">2012-04-26</Field>
    <Field name="Material" readOnly="X"> Congress </Field>
</Item>
```

and I want to transform it into this format (note that node names need to be replaced with a corresponsding attribute name)

```
<Item name="Alpha">
    <CreationDateTime >2012-04-26</CreationDateTime>
    <Material readOnly="X"> Congress </Material>
</Item>
```

What may be the quickest way to do it in jquery.  This has to happen in a table with 1000's of record and thus it has to be efficient.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered doing this transformation using XSLT? Seems it is for exactly this kind of problems that XSLT was created.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses jQuery's map function to translate between the documents. It gets the basic job done, and can probably be extended further to suit the needs of your complete document.

A few existing issues:

- The casing of the tags in the output is lowercase, which I can't seem to find an easy solution for.
- I have no clue how it will perform on thousands of records. :)

Source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var XML = 
    '<Item name="Alpha">' +
    '<Field name="CreationDateTime">2012-04-26</Field>' + 
    '<Field name="Material" readOnly="X"> Congress </Field>' +
'</Item>';

$(XML).map(function() {             
    function map() {
        if ($(this).is("Item")) {
            var result = $("<Item>").attr("name", "Alpha");                     
            var children = $(this).children().map(map);


            $(children).each(function() {
                result.append(this);
            });

            return result;
        }

        if ($(this).is("Field")) {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");

            var result = $("<" + name + ">");

            // Transfer other attributes
            $(this.attributes).each(function() {
                if (this.name === "name")
                    return;

                result.attr(this.name, this.value);
            });

            result.text( $(this).text() );
            return result;
        }
    };

    var result = $(XML).map(map);
});
});
</script>
```